# How can I transform left side into right side in Logic Propositional?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have this formulas:

$$(P \to Q) \to (P \land Q) = (\lnot P \to  Q) \land (Q \to  P), $$

How can I transform left side into right side, or virse-versa, using Logic Propositional?

Comment: They are not equivalent; the former one is true if $P$ does, whereas the latter one is invalid.

Comment: There is some steps can be loaded in the same normal form?

Comment: They can't have same normal term, as they are not equivalent.

Comment: The question is:

"verify each of the following pairs of equivalent formulas by transforming formulas on both sides of the sign = into the same normal form"

Comment: And I can't do it

Comment: You can prove the right-hand side from the left-hand side because the right-hand side is false, but not vice versa.

Comment: @HanulJeon No, both are equivalent to $P$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I should recognize I had made immense mistake.

Comment: I do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Use *implication equivalence* and *distribution* to meet in the middle.$$\begin{align} &(P\to Q)\to (P\wedge Q)
\\=~& 
\\=~& 
\\=~&  
\\=~& P\wedge\top & \top\text{ is $``$true"}
\\=~& P 
\\=~& P\vee \bot& \bot\text{ is $``$false"}
\\=~& 
\\=~& 
\\=~& (\neg P\to Q)\wedge(Q\to P)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use **truth table** for both logical expressions $(P\to Q)\to (P\wedge Q)$ and $(\lnot P \to  Q) \land (Q \to  P)$.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c| c|c| c|}
\hline
 P 
   & Q                   
       & (P\to Q)
          &  (P\wedge Q)
            & (P\to Q)\to (P\wedge Q)  
\\\hline
V & V & V & V & V                        
\\\hline
V & F & F & F & V                         
\\\hline
F  & V & V & F & F                         
\\\hline
F & F & V  & F & F                        
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
and
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c| c|c| c|c| c|}
\hline
 P 
   & Q
     & \lnot P 
       & Q                 
          & (\lnot P \to  Q)
            &  (Q \to  P) 
              & (\lnot P \to  Q) \land (Q \to  P) 
\\\hline
V & V & F & V & V & V & V
\\\hline 
V & F & F & V & V & V & V
\\\hline 
F & V & V & V & V & F & F
\\\hline 
F & F & V & F & F & V & F
\\\hline                      
\end{array}
$$